# How to find Var($\bar{X}-\bar{Y}$) , the variance of the difference between the sample means?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

So I tried to do this my own way but I'm not sure if it's correct. I used the equation for variance to get this answer, but I'm not sure if it matches up with what the answer is. Also to be honest, I'm not sure why I'm dividing by m+n? I just sort of guessed but I don't really get why. I thought I'd have to multiply by m and n, not divide. I'm guessing that's because you take out the constant when you calculate variance? [image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your comments on the question are incomprehensible. For any random variables $X$ and $Y$, we have $\text{Var}(X+Y)=\text{Var}(X)+\text{Var}(Y)+2\cdot\text{Cov}(X,Y)$. Moreover, $\text{Var}(aX)=a^2\text{Var}(X)$, when $a$ is a constant. In your case, $\text{Var}(\bar{X})=\text{Var}(\frac{1}{n}\sum X_i)=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum\text{Var}(X_i)=\frac{1}{n^2}\cdot n \sigma^2=\sigma^2/n$, where the second step follows because the $X_i$ are a random sample and therefore independent, hence their covariance is zero.

Comment: I am puzzled, it looks as if it should be $\frac{\sigma_1^2}{m}+\frac{\sigma_2^2}{n}$.

Comment: You need to clearly explain what "your way" and "the formula" are. It would also be in your best interest to understand what the distribution of $\bar X-\bar Y$ is. It's also not clear if you understand what $\bar X$ means.

Comment: Also, no if the part you wrote for b is your answer, then it doesn't match the given answer. Your answer is not even a real number, and the given answer is wrong. It should be $\sigma_1^2/m+\sigma_2^2/n$.

Comment: Hi everyone! Thanks so much for all the responses. Yeah I'm unfortunately pretty confused, as you can probably tell. I was using this formula (The Equation Defining Variance)  to try and see if I could figure it out myself: http://www.sciencebuddies.org/science-fair-projects/project_data_analysis_variance_std_deviation.shtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope a few extra sentences can clear up some of your confusion.

In the notation of the printed problem, the variances of the sample means are $V(\bar X) = \sigma_1^2/n$ and $V(\bar Y) = \sigma_2^2/m$.

Without knowing the context of the chapter you took this from, I'd say it is
reasonable to assume these are two *independent* samples. That implies that
$\bar X$ and $\bar Y$ are independent random variables.

In general, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, then
$Var(aX + bY) = a^2Var(X) + b^2Var(y),$ so that $Var(X - Y) = Var(X)+Var(Y),$
letting $a = 1$ and $b = -1.$

Then

$$Var(\bar X - \bar Y) = \frac{\sigma_1^2}{n} + \frac{\sigma_2^2}{m},$$

*Note:* The covariance plays a role when the two sample means are
not independent. That is the reason for the last sentence in part b.

I'm guessing that this exercise is to get you ready to find a confidence
interval or do a test on the difference between two population means.
The estimate of $\mu_1 - \mu_2$ is $\bar X - \bar Y.$ Part of the rationale
for that statement is that $E(\bar X - \bar Y) = \mu_1 - \mu_2.$ The variance
of this estimate is what we just derived in the displayed equation.

---

A little more background--because you wondered about $n$'s in denominators.

$$E(\bar X) = E\left(\frac{X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n}{n}\right)
= \frac{1}{n}E(X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n) = \frac{1}{n}[E(X_1)+E(X_2)+\cdots + E(X_n)] = \frac{1}{n}[\mu_1 + \mu_1 + \cdots + \mu_1] \\
 = \frac{1}{n}(n\mu_1) = \mu_1.$$

Also, because $Var(aX) = a^2 Var(X),$ and taking $a = 1/n,$ we have

$$Var(\bar X) = Var\left(\frac{X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n}{n}\right)
= \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2 Var(X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n) = \frac{1}{n^2}[Var(X_1)+Var(X_2)+\cdots +  Var(X_n)] = \frac{1}{n^2}[\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_1^2 + \cdots + \sigma_1^2] \\
 = \frac{1}{n^2}(n\sigma_1^2) = \sigma_1^2/n.$$

This says that $\bar X$ is a less-variable (more stable) random variable
than any one of the $X_i$'s. And the variance gets smaller as the
sample size gets larger. That idea is really important in inferential
statistics. More information (carefully collected) is better than less.

Comment: ahhh thank you so so much! I truly appreciate it.